CannonJS takes allot of force to start moving body
I'm making a movement system with cannonjs and threejs and I have reached a road block.
Basicly, when the player presses the W key it requires alot of force to start and keep moving.
To make the player move i need to make the SPEED_OFFSET to 2700 while it should only need to be 20 (according to my calculations)
Most of the code related is in the player class but I also left the rest.
Player Class:
import * as THREE from "three"
import * as CANNON from "cannon"

import { RigidBox, Vec3Array } from "../components/body";
import { createBasicShadowMaterial } from "../components/material";
import { GamePhysics } from "../physics";
import { GameScene } from "../scene";


const SPEED_OFFSET = 2700;

export class Player {
   scene: GameScene;
   physics: GamePhysics;
   model: RigidBox;

   speed: number = 10;


   constructor (scene: GameScene, physics: GamePhysics) {  
      this.scene = scene;
      this.physics = physics;
   
      this.createPlayerModel = this.createPlayerModel.bind(this);
      const { model } = this.createPlayerModel();
      this.model = model;
   }


   private createPlayerModel(): {model: RigidBox} {
      const model = new RigidBox(createBasicShadowMaterial(0xf1c27d), this.scene, this.physics);
      model.body.fixedRotation = true;
      model.setMass(50);
      model.setSize(1,2,1);
      model.setPosition(0, 3, 0);
      model.body.updateMassProperties();
      model.setAnchored(false);

      return { model };
   }
}


export class LocalPlayer extends Player {
   controlsDisabled: boolean = false;

   private wDown: boolean = false;
   private sDown: boolean = false;
   private aDown: boolean = false;
   private dDown: boolean = false;
   private spaceDown: boolean = false;


   constructor (scene: GameScene, physics: GamePhysics) {
      super(scene, physics);
   
      (this.model.mesh.material as THREE.Material).transparent = true;
      (this.model.mesh.material as THREE.Material).opacity = 1;

      this.controls = this.controls.bind(this);
      this.controls();
   }

   private controls() {
      addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
         if (this.controlsDisabled) return;

         switch (event.key) {
            case "w":
               this.wDown = false;
               break;

            case "s":
               this.sDown = false;
               break;

            case "a":
               this.aDown = false;
               break;

            case "d":
               this.dDown = false;
               break;

            case " ":
               this.spaceDown = false;
               break;
         }
      });

      addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
         if (this.controlsDisabled) return;

         switch (event.key) {
            case "w":
               this.wDown = true;
               break;

            case "s":
               this.sDown = true;
               break;

            case "a":
               this.aDown = true;
               break;

            case "d":
               this.dDown = true;
               break;

            case " ":
               this.spaceDown = true;
               break;
         }
      });
   }

   public update(now: number, prevTime: number) {
      const delta = (now - prevTime) / 1000;
      const moveVector: Vec3Array = [0, 0, 0];

      if (this.wDown) {
         moveVector[2] += 1
      }
      
      if (this.sDown) {
         moveVector[2] -= 1
      }
      
      if (this.aDown) {
         moveVector[0] += 1
      }

      if (this.dDown) {
         moveVector[0] -= 1
      }

      if (moveVector[0] !== 0 && moveVector[2] !== 0) {
         const diagFactor = 1 / Math.sqrt(2);
         moveVector[0] *= diagFactor;
         moveVector[2] *= diagFactor;
      }

      moveVector[0] *= this.speed * delta * SPEED_OFFSET;
      moveVector[2] *= this.speed * delta * SPEED_OFFSET;

      let impulseVec = new CANNON.Vec3(moveVector[0], moveVector[1], moveVector[2]);
      impulseVec = this.model.body.quaternion.vmult(impulseVec);

      this.model.body.applyImpulse(impulseVec, new CANNON.Vec3(0,0,0));
   }
}

Camera class:
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Player } from "./model/player";

export class GameCamera extends THREE.PerspectiveCamera {
   player: Player;

   constructor (player: Player) {
      super(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
      this.position.set(13, 0, 0);
      this.lookAt(0,0,0);

      this.player = player;
   }

   public update(now: number) {
      this.position.set(this.player.model.body.position.x, this.player.model.body.position.y + 1, this.player.model.body.position.z);
   
      const getCameraRotate = new THREE.Vector3();
      this.getWorldDirection(getCameraRotate);
      getCameraRotate.y = 0;
      getCameraRotate.add(this.player.model.mesh.position);
      this.player.model.mesh.lookAt(getCameraRotate);
      
      const q = this.player.model.mesh.quaternion;
      this.player.model.body.quaternion.set(q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w);
   }
}

Physics class:
import * as CANNON from "cannon";
import { RigidBox } from "./components/body";


export class GamePhysics extends CANNON.World  {
   objects: RigidBox[] = [];
   
   constructor () {
      super();
      this.gravity.set(0, -7, 0)
   }

   public updateWorldState() {
      this.objects.forEach((obj: RigidBox) => {
         obj.mesh.position.copy(obj.body.position);
         obj.mesh.quaternion.copy(obj.body.quaternion);
      });
   }
}

body class:
import * as THREE from "three"
import * as CANNON from "cannon"
import { GameScene } from "../scene"
import { GamePhysics } from "../physics"


export type Vec3Array = [number, number, number];

export class RigidBox {
   mesh: THREE.Mesh;
   body: CANNON.Body;
   mass: number = 1;
   anchored: boolean = true;
   world: GamePhysics;
   scene: THREE.Scene;
   __Destroyed: boolean = false;

   constructor (
      material: THREE.Material,
      scene: GameScene,
      world: GamePhysics,
   ) {
      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
      this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      this.mesh.castShadow = true;
      this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;
      scene.add(this.mesh);

      const shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(.5, .5, .5));
      this.body = new CANNON.Body({mass: 1});
      this.body.addShape(shape);
      world.addBody(this.body);
      
      this.body.mass = 0;
      this.body.updateMassProperties();
      this.body.position.set(0, 0, 0);

      world.objects.push(this);
      this.world = world;
      this.scene = scene;
   }

   public setPosition(...pos: Vec3Array) {
      this.mesh.position.set(...pos);
      this.body.position.set(...pos);
   }

   public setSize(...size: Vec3Array) {
      this.mesh.scale.set(...size);

      const newShape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2, size[2] / 2));

      this.body.shapes = [];
      this.body.addShape(newShape);
  
      this.body.updateMassProperties();
  
      this.body.computeAABB();
  
      this.body.position.set(this.body.position.x, this.body.position.y, this.body.position.z);
      this.body.quaternion.set(this.body.quaternion.x, this.body.quaternion.y, this.body.quaternion.z, this.body.quaternion.w);
      this.body.velocity.set(this.body.velocity.x, this.body.velocity.y, this.body.velocity.z);
      this.body.angularVelocity.set(this.body.angularVelocity.x, this.body.angularVelocity.y, this.body.angularVelocity.z);
   }

   public setRoation(...rotation: Vec3Array) {
      this.mesh.rotation.set(...rotation);
      this.body.quaternion.set(this.mesh.quaternion.x, this.mesh.quaternion.y, this.mesh.quaternion.z, this.mesh.quaternion.w);
   }

   public setMass(mass: number) {
      this.mass = mass;
      
      if (!this.anchored) {
         this.body.mass = this.mass;
         this.body.updateMassProperties();
      }
   }

   public setAnchored(a: boolean) {
      this.anchored = a;
      this.body.mass = this.anchored ? 0 : this.mass;

      if (a) {
         this.body.velocity.set(0, 0, 0);
         this.body.angularVelocity.set(0, 0, 0);
      }

      this.body.updateMassProperties();
   }

   public applyForce(...force: Vec3Array) {
      this.body.applyForce(new CANNON.Vec3(...force), new CANNON.Vec3(0, 0, 0));
   }

   public destroy() {
      if (this.__Destroyed) return;
      
      this.scene.remove(this.mesh); // @ts-expect-error < world.removeBody exsists, TS is just dumb
      this.world.removeBody(this.body);
      
      this.world.objects.splice(this.world.objects.indexOf(this), 1);
      
      this.__Destroyed = true;
   }
}

Main Module:
import * as THREE from "three";

import Stats from "three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js";

import { GameScene } from "./scene";
import { GameCamera } from "./camera";
import { GamePhysics } from "./physics";
import { GameRenderer } from "./renderer";

import { RigidBox } from "./components/body";
import { createBasicLamberColorMaterial } from "./components/material";
import { loadSceneLights } from "./lights";
import { LocalPlayer, Player } from "./model/player";
import { GameControls } from "./controls";


export class Game {
   scene: GameScene = new GameScene();
   physics: GamePhysics = new GamePhysics();
   stats: Stats = new Stats();
   renderer: GameRenderer;
   controls: GameControls;
   camera: GameCamera;
   plr: LocalPlayer;

   previewsTime: number = 0;
   accumulator: number = 0;


   constructor () {
      this.stats.showPanel(0);
      document.body.appendChild(this.stats.dom);
      
      const floor = new RigidBox(createBasicLamberColorMaterial(0x129619), this.scene, this.physics);
      floor.setSize(20, 1, 20);
      
      this.plr = new LocalPlayer(this.scene, this.physics);
      
      loadSceneLights(this.scene);
      
      this.camera = new GameCamera(this.plr);
      this.controls = new GameControls(this.camera, document.createElement("div"));
      this.renderer = new GameRenderer(this.camera);
      
      this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

      this.gameLoop = this.gameLoop.bind(this);
      this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(this.gameLoop);
   }

   
   private gameLoop(now: number) {  
      this.stats.begin();
      this.accumulator += (now * 0.001) - (this.previewsTime * 0.001);
      
      if (this.accumulator >= 1 / 60) { // capped at 60 FPS
         this.physics.step(1 / 60);
         this.accumulator -= 1 / 60;
      }
      
      this.plr.update(now, this.previewsTime);

      this.camera.update(now);
      this.physics.updateWorldState();

      this.renderer.renderScene(this.scene, this.camera);

      this.stats.end();
      this.previewsTime = now;
   }
}

I tried basicly everything
